# Simulation isn't working for high voltage amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, high-voltage, multisim, powermosfet

Been trying to simulate on multisim a circuit I saw about high voltage amplifier:

[image: schematic]

Schematic source seems to be:

[EDN Design Ideas, 2004](https://www.edn.com/wp-content/uploads/EDN_Design_Ideas_2004_.pdf) - page 123 of 155 (displayed page number 110)
**High-voltage amplifier uses simplified circuit**
*Jui-I Tsai, Jun-Ming Shieh, Tai-Shan Liao, and*
*Ching-Cheng Teng, National Chiao Tung Unversity, Taiwan*

There are also corrections in the comments below this original article:

[EDN - High-voltage amplifier uses simplified circuit](https://www.edn.com/high-voltage-amplifier-uses-simplified-circuit/)
October 14, 2004

---

The input is 8 Vp-p and 100Hz and reached to output of 1800 Vp-p and 100Hz.
The publisher mentioned he used the following parts to build it:
OP07 , LM356,  MTP2P50E and BUK456800B.

In the multisim database, I couldn't find these exact parts (perhaps because companies stopped creating them). So, instead I used the following parts for the following simulation:
OP07, LF356H, MTP2P50EG and NDD03N80Z-1G.

[image: Upper]

[image]

For input 8 Vp-p and 100Hz, I got the result of approx. 8 V:
[image]

And I can't figure out whats the problem with the design I implanted on the multisim, as I don't get the high voltage that is desired.
Thank you for anyone who reads this and tries to help me, much appriciated !

Comment: Have you tried it at DC or very low frequency? With those very high gate resistors and no compensating capacitors, it won't work very fast.

Comment: @KevinWhite I just tried switching to low frequency and then with DC, but no promising results, unfortunately.

Comment: Your PMOS connections are wrong. In the original, sources to the top, drains to the bottom. In yours, sources to the bottom, drains to the top.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I noticed that in the original paper as well before, tried to connect them as he did, yet it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: Looks like some of those "dot" connection points are mis-placed, so badly that the circuitry intention is not immediately apparent.

Comment: In your circuit, the Q5 source (assuming you fix the problem Rohat pointed out) is not connected to +1000 V and the Q12 source is not connected to -1000 V. This is very likely connected to your not seeing high voltages at the output.

Comment: @glen_geek Thank you for responding, I followed the original publish once again, but the "junctions" seem connected right. Yes, it looks pretty messed, but I am positive the junctions are connected well. Perhaps you see a bad spot that I missed?

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you for responding, I just connected the 1000v and -1000v to their destination (even though the publisher didn't do it) , and now I get a more flat line, almost like its DC.

Comment: Since the schematic is drawn so misleading, you cannot expect to get results. If you can, ask the owner of the site, or the one posting that picture for clarifications. Otherwise, either try to make your own, or search for other schematics.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I agree, it is very misleading schematics as he says one thing on the components, and uses others. But since he posted the promising results, I assumed he got them from his own schematic and that his article is correct. I will try to contact him and listen to people's solutions here.

Answer (score 4):

I found some errors in the original schematic, they are corrected.
[image: eredeti]

For newer FETs, the quiescent current had to be set. I set this to 5mA with R19 and R25. (14k instead of 10k.) There is no point in looking in front of the LF356, there is only a -2 gain there (OP07).
[image: mostemető]

The DC gain is approx. 174x.

DC transfer characteristics:
[image: dctrans]

At 100Hz, the gain is approx. half the DC gain.
[image: 100hz]

Comment: Thank you so much for spending the time and helping me out! I will try it out. Are there any other similar components to FQD2N100 and FQD3P50? and is it possible to reach output of 1.3kV with this circuit? Thank you so much again

Comment: I liked it, so I dealt with it. :) NMOS is not a problem, there is a large selection above 600V. I did not find more than 500V from PMOS. In the first stage, they operate at [half](https://imgur.com/a/tRe0Yzw) the supply voltage. The PMOS model is starting to limit at 550V. It is important that its leakage current is small at 500V because the first stage operates at 280uA (FQD3P50 has 1uA). A similar forward characteristic is required at low currents (below 5mA) for the working point to be well adjustable. If you find a minimum 700V PMOS device, it can run from 1.3kV.

Comment: Appreciate everything you have done for me!  Thank you for your guidance! I got one last small question if you don't mind. What program are you using in order to build the circuits and simulations?

Comment: I just used Tina (v 9.3) now, but I have LTSpice, Tina-TI, and PSpice for TI 2020.
Depending on what I want to model, I always need another one.

Comment: I see. About the Vp (Voltage peak) of the last simulation you sent, will it work with lower voltage input? for example, maximum 5Vpp?

Comment: Yes. The gain can be adjusted with resistor R16. (A smaller resistor results in a higher gain.) A higher gain results in a higher output offset voltage, so the operational amplifier will also need an offset adjusting potentiometer. If the construction intention is serious, a low leakage current Zener (10-15V) should also be installed in each FET gate source. (On and off transient protection.)

Comment: I thought about adding Zener as well to each FET gate source, now I can confirm it will work thanks to you. Is this scheme possible to construct on PCB? are there any rules or laws about this scheme, for example not using normal wiring and such. I plan to test it and make it to PCB, and was wondering if its possible and what are the limitations / rules

Comment: Yes, PCBs can be designed with protection diodes. Because these are very small currents and low cutoff frequencies, design is not critical. The values ​​of R4 and R21 (14k) will then be critical to adjust the current around 5mA at the output stage.

Comment: Understood. So no need for special wires and such?

Comment: Nothing special will be needed. The output stage FETs will need a heat sink. Without control, 250Vx5mA = 1.25W of power is generated on them. The 5mA may be reduced, but the [crossover distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_distortion) will soon appear around zero at lower currents.

Comment: Interesting question my professor came up with. If instead of 4 PMOS and 4 NMOS , I add another pair, so it will be 5 or 6 PMOS in row and 5 or 6 PMOS in row. Won't it grant me higher voltage output?

Comment: Of course, this is possible. The problem is not in the output stage where there are 4 FETs. The first stage should be redesigned to operate more FETs at higher voltages.

Comment: Is there any way you can tell me which is the correct SPICE models for the FQD2N100 and FQD3P50? I got the models from the internet, but it seems it doesn't work well

Comment: Thank you for the hard work and your time! When you converted them (I am using Multisim), were they under the family of MOS? or POWER MOS? When I try to add the SPICE model to one of them, it gives me errors about the netlists

Comment: I also found simpler [models](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GaE2T1bNMaodqYGTMaRTpawEVenkJzV3) to see if you can use them better.

Comment: I just simulated it, and unfortunately , I don't get the desired voltage. I used the recent FET models you sent me and the exact LF356, yet I do not achieve it. Is there any way I could sent you the simulation , just to check if I did something incorrect?

Comment: For new FET models, the value of the 14k resistors must be slightly adjusted. You can find the full plan [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GaE2T1bNMaodqYGTMaRTpawEVenkJzV3). The .tsc file is the complete plan in the TINA-TI version. The pictures show the circuit diagram, the DC transfer characteristic and a 50Hz transient.

Comment: Your drive is very helpful, thank you very much! the 1000v and the negative -1000v, what can generate it? is it something I can purchase and use on the pcb?