# High voltage high frequency amplifier

Tags: amplifier, powermosfet, power-amplifier

I have copied this amplifier design below for 1 kV. Is it possible to achieve 300 V peak to peak output by using this design and I want to achieve 2 MHz bandwidth. Is it possible to achieve such bandwidth with this design because it is a design for 100 Hz?

[image: schematic]

Schematic source: Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange
Answer by [csabahu](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/260047/csabahu) to question "[Simulation isn't working for high voltage amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/521717)"
[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)

Comment: +/- 1 kV supplies for 300 V pp = +/- 150 V output??? Headroom to burn. You'll have to throw away those stacked output devices, for frequencies much higher than 100 Hz.

Comment: i am using for 300VPeak to peak not for 1kv.so i will make changes according requirements.

Comment: What are your range of input frequencies and what actual power supplies will you use? It might help if you give a clear indication of the application too. Output load impedance is vital to know. Use of a simulation tool will vastly help you.

Comment: Output Load is 25 ohm. Bandwidth (-3dBV): 1kHz to 2MHz.I have to use for piezo ultrasonic transducers. Power Supply +/- 200 V

Comment: @Khan_1 please read Neil's comment more closely: you *use* 1 kV, as *supply* voltage.

Comment: its just a reference design i will modify it according to my require voltages.

Comment: @Khan_1 no, you just made your question worse: this amplifier does *not* amplify to 1 kV. It **needs** 1 kV supply to amplify to < 1 kV (like most amplifiers).

Comment: What is the capacitance of the load?

Comment: Khan_1 said: "for piezo ultrasonic transducers" This is not a resistive load.  Be sure to model your transducer connected to the output.  You may be surprised.

Comment: @bobflux  I go throw one of your solution for high voltage Mosfet amplifier.https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVDFh.png.  it will work for my application.

Comment: Load Impedance is 25 ohm

Comment: @Khan_1 - Hi, You copied that schematic from another user's answer without giving an appropriate reference/citation and therefore broke [this site rule](/help/referencing). I added a reference for you. Please make sure to follow that site rule in future and avoid taking credit for someone else's work. Thanks.

Comment: That won't run at 1MHz, for this it needs a lot more slew rate and output current, a piezo is a capacitor and you need to check its characteristics

Comment: Thanks i will come back to you.

Comment: 300V pk-to-pk, is very roughly 100V RMS when driven with a sine signal.  If the load was 25R resistive, this equates to roughly 400W at up to 2MHz.  Slew rates are around 2KV/us. With a capacitive load the situation is more complex still.  To settle on the best system design, I'd strongly suggest you consider more carefully what you are trying to achieve, in particular whether you really need a linear amp over this range, or whether some form of pulse or resonant driver might suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Your design does work. And this is how I know:

I designed and build that exact circuit in the mid 1970s. The only difference is that I used capacitors across each resistor in the divider. I sent the design to Motorola and they published in their MOSFET Applications Handbook! I was so proud!

Dr. Jan Hall used that amplifier to drive piezos to steer lasers and [he got the Nobel Prize for his work](https://www.nist.gov/nist-and-nobel/jan-hall#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CJan%E2%80%9D%20Hall%20received%20the%202005,of%20the%20laser%20in%201960.).

But that was 50 years ago, before we had 2 kV MOSFETs. Today we have a nice selection of [2 kV + MOSFETs](https://www.digikey.com/short/zvbp9c72). There is no need to stack low voltage MOSFETs.

So, to answer your question: your design is OK, but it's not necessary.

Comment: oh wow! I just did a rough estimate based on the typical 18 nC of the FQD3P50's gate, and the resistors through which they are charged and discharged and came to the conclusion that the exact circuit as shown was intentionally bandwidth-limited; and then I, it seems falsely, inferred that the designer would probably have other objectives with their stacked topology – probably noise and robustness – that conflict with speed. Sometimes it's really nice to know I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Large MOSFET gate capacitances, and of that a stack of four on each side, will severely, and intentionally, limit your bandwidth.

You need to design a simpler circuit. It's anyways a bit surprising that you've designed such a complex beast to begin with. Go simpler!